# Kivy sound volume. python

Tags: python, kivy

How do I display and set the volume when "set_volumemore11" is pressed?

```
class MainPage(Screen):
    filenamemore11 = 'synth1.wav'
    soundmore11 = ObjectProperty(None, allownone=True)
    volumemore11 = NumericProperty(1.0)

    def openmore1(self, *args):
        self.more11slider = Slider(orientation='horizontal', min=0, max=1, value= self.volumemore11)
        self.more11slider.bind(on_value=self.set_volumemore11(self.value))
        self.add_widget(self.more11slider)

    def playmore11(self, *args):
        if self.soundmore11 is None:
            self.soundmore11 = SoundLoader.load(self.filenamemore11)
        if self.soundmore11.status != 'stop':
            self.soundmore11.stop()
        self.soundmore11.loop = False
        self.soundmore11.volumemore11 = self.volumemore11
        self.soundmore11.play()

    def set_volumemore11(self, volumemore11):
        self.volumemore11 = volumemore11
        if self.soundmore11:
            self.soundmore11.volumemore11 = volumemore11
```

This is what I have so far, I have tried everything I know, including `value= self.soundmore11.volumemore11` to `on_value=self.set_volumemore11(self.value)`, and it still doesn't work. Any type of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def openmore1(self, *args):
    self.more11slider = Slider(orientation='horizontal',step=0.1, min=0, max=1, value= self.volumemore11)
    self.add_widget(self.more11slider)

def playmore11(self, *args):
    if self.soundmore11 is None:
        self.soundmore11 = SoundLoader.load(self.filenamemore11)
    if self.soundmore11.status != 'stop':
        self.soundmore11.stop()
    self.soundmore11.loop = False
    self.soundmore11.volumemore11 = self.volumemore11
    self.soundmore11.play()
```

I forgot to answer this question but, her is an easy way... Also you can change the volume by doing something like this when the vol button is pressed.

```
def set_volumemore11(self, *args):
    self.volumemore11 += 0.2
    if self.volumemore11 ==: 1.2
        self.volumemore11 = 0.0
```